# JDBC MS SQL Server Kerberos Auth

Tags: java, sql-server, security, jdbc, kerberos

I have a MS SQL Server RDBMS which uses Kerberos to authenticate the users.

From a Windows machine if I set the database URL to

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DB_NAME:DB_PORT;integratedSecurity=true
```

and add the appropriate `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to the path, everything works.

However I would like to use the Java Kerberos authentication, in order to be able to use the same code in *nix machines too.

So my DB URL becomes

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DB_NAME:DB_PORT;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

When I am running the code I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:796)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:667)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:580)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I have to add that I am using the default `Krb5LoginModule` that is provided by the JDBC driver.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using MS JDBC or Open JTDS?

Comment: @gbn I am using the MS JDBC. sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: @nikkatsa Did you find a solution?

Comment: @nikkatsa I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The [MS JDBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx) docs states

> When using authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos, you must specify the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) in the serverName property. Otherwise, an error will occur (Server not found in Kerberos database).

So your URL becomes

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DB_NAME.domain.net:DB_PORT;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

Comment: Indeed i am using the full domain name to the database. The error i am getting is different than the one specified in the MS documentation.

Comment: Pretty sure this format is wrong. I don't see where you can put "DB_NAME." before the host name.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15.  I think one way is to add a property to the end of the URL like this: `;database=DB_NAME`

Comment: @splashout true, but I just copied OP example. They mean servername:instanceport

Answer (score 2):

You have failed either to supply the `login.conf` or the entry within that config file which uses the `Krb5LoginModule`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a *Kerberos subsystem* (preferably the [MIT Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/)) configured on your *NIX system? It is required in order to obtain a *Ticket Granting Ticket* (from a *Key Distribution Centre*) to further authenticate to an SQL Server. See also [Wikipedia entry on Kerberos protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29), [some guide from MS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122.aspx).

Comment: I guess he expects to use ActiveDirectory Kerberos implementation and his SQL Server windows system is registered in that domain.

Answer (score 1):

Are you executing the code in a Windows system? If this is your scenario, the problem could be related to the registry entry AllowTgtSessionKey.

In this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122%28v=sql.110%29.aspx you can find the next intruction:

> 1. Set AllowTgtSessionKey to 1 in the registry for Windows. For more
>      information, see [Kerberos protocol registry entries and KDC
>      configuration keys in Windows Server 2003.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/837361)